# Running PowerShell 2 in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to run PowerShell 2 in VSCode so I added the following to my settings but it has no effect.  Is this possible to do? If so how can I configure the integrated terminal to use 2.0?

"

```
"powershell.developer.powerShellExePath": "c:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -version 2",

"powershell.powerShellExePath": "c:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -version 2",
```

Comment: AFAIK PowerShell v2 is not supported in VSCode.

Comment: Not only is v2 not supported in VSCode, it's been [deprecated by Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/08/24/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation/) and you should be moving away from it as fast as is reasonable.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use it on occasion